# Regarding dbms_job.submit

Tags: oracle, plsql, job-scheduling

I am kind of new to scheduling jobs in Oracle. Consider that i am using dbms_job.submit to run multiple Jobs(Procedure) in oracle. Will each job have different sessions?

```
dbms_job.submit(1, 'begin proc; end;' );
dbms_job.submit(2, 'begin proc; end;' );
```

Now the question is will the jobs running (2 jobs mentioned above) have different session id or the same?

The reason i am asking you the question is because imagine that both the jobs are running parallel, and the JOB 1 is gonna commit as it got completed successfully, but during that time JOB 2 got failed and the rollback occurred. During this scenario will the records that is to be committed by JOB1 will also get rollback as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Oracle documentation is quite clear](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96521/jobq.htm#1001): background jobs run in their own session. So there is no relationship between the sessions of job `1` and job `2`.

---

Incidentally, if you are using a modern version of the database (11g or later) you really should use DBMS_SCHEDULER rather than the deprecated DBMS_JOB. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/schedover.htm#ADMIN033).